# Encoding ascii symbol within html

Tags: python, html, ascii

I'm sending an html over an Email and some lines of the html should look like this:

`Monday 11/06 3pm W - 267°`

there are many lines using that symbol and they are within diffrent tags on the html for example:

```
<p> results are the following:
    <ul>
        <li> Monday 11/06 3pm W - 267°
        <li> Tuesday 12/06 3pm W - 279°
    </ul>
 </p>
```

for the encoding I use:

```
html = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(html)
```

so that my tags will be encoded as html tags.
I've relaized that in order to send the degrees symbol I need to encode the html as ascii' However the result is sending my whole html as plain text.

The main problem is that the symbols I use are not at the end of the html or at the beggining of it so I'm not sure how to attach it correctly.

if I'm tryging to send the ascii symbol as text I recieve the following exception:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 617: ordinal not in range(128)`

thanks alot to the helpers.

Comment: Which version of Python and what the str encoding of the `html` value (i.e., how is it obtained?) are going to be important.

Answer (score 0):

To send message directly as html:

```
text = '''
<p> results are the following:
    <ul>
        <li> Monday 11/06 3pm W - 267°</li>
        <li> Tuesday 12/06 3pm W - 279°</li>
    </ul>
 </p>
'''
msg = MIMEText(text, 'html')
```

Comment: That's the reason I asked the question in first place...UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 617: ordinal not in range(128) @Goran